# Difference between 'USING' and || in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I just need to run a basic SELECT query in PL/SQL code. The following code works perfectly fine:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM ' || 'TNAME';
END;
/
```

But following code

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM :1' USING 'TNAME';
END;
/
```

gives error saying

ORA-00903: invalid table name

ORA-06512: at line 2

903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

*Cause:
*Action:

**Can I not pass table name using "USING" in any way ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Oracle documentation states:

> "You can only use placeholders in places where you can substitute
>   variables in the SQL statement, such as conditional tests in WHERE
>   clauses. You cannot use placeholders for the names of schema objects.
>   For the right way, see "[Passing Schema Object Names As
>   Parameters.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i14257)"